# End user credentials for own Google Sheet access

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, credentials

I have written an app in Python that accesses a Google Sheet, gathers some data and writes the data back to the sheet. It works. I am wondering about how I get the end user to create a credentials file for their sheet so the program can read and write to their file. Is the best way just to walk them through creating the JSON file and turning on sharing? It seems a little techy for a typical user.

Comment: Use oauth so they can get access without providing you any credentials

Comment: This might be more appropriate for Software Engineering stack exchange; stack overflow is for troubleshooting code ONLY. You can also look at Python forums and IRC.

Answer (score 1):

You need to go through the OAuth process and provide an OAuth token when your application needs to modify another user's sheet.

You can find more information here: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing#OAuth2Authorizing